# News feed for web page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, ajax

I'm building a website that will have a news feed (similar in idea to facebook and twitter) ...

Other sections in the website will also be using the same idea.

I've already build the DB and working on the HTML/PHPs with my team. I need to know how to create a news feed which is scrollable like facebook. Don't need to set a limit to it.

**UPDATE**

After further searching, I found that what I need is news ticker ...

Comment: Do you have any code your using at the moment?

Comment: @SamWarren: All I have is just the basic of the pages ... Nothing for the feed except the loading from DB and echoing on page.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider [**Feed Creator**](http://feedcreator.org/).

It'll do everything you want without reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I believe you misunderstood what I need ... I'm not looking for RSS feed ... I need a scroll page like facebook that will post the news updates as soon as they are published to the DB ...
I was thinking of using JQuery for this to open another page, get all updates newer that the top-most one and then load it ... But I don't know how to do it!!